# Out side touch should be enable when we add view in window manager

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-windowmanager

Out side touch should be enable when we add view in window manager but in my case outside touch disable when i add view in window manager.

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    params.flags =
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN |

                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |

                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS 
    ;
    params.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.shagun_notify,null);
    wm.addView(view, params);
```

Comment: use WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH for touch outside.

Comment: i have used but not working

Comment: what you trying , if someone click the window manager then view is gone? right

Comment: View should be there not gone...Actually i want to add a view at run time at any where in bottom of app view  that's why i am using window manager and outside touch enable when view added.

Comment: can elaborate what you are trying to do and what your problem , i am not getting it

Comment: i want to create a common view that i can add any where in bottom of app at the run time...how can i do this?

Comment: any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this its working you can try this .must take the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>` in mainifests.xml

```
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams dialogParams = new 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
        View activityView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom, null);
        wm.addView(activityView, dialogParams);
```

bottom.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @RamiJemli have you given overlay permission on run time ?

Comment: @RamiJemli i changed my java code , now its work outside touchable .