# WindowManager not allowing touch outside

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I am trying to create a layout that overlays other apps. More specifically, I want users to be able to interact with other apps and the overlay at the same time.

I tried this inside a service, but it's not working.

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089783/out-side-touch-should-be-enable-when-we-add-view-in-window-manager

Comment: That doesn't work.